# set header 410 for random generated folder path

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, regex

I have thousand of error URL with patterns like this

```
 https://example.com/feeds/74750882288885xxx/comments/default
```

where `74750882288885xxx` is a random number, I need help to set this URL to be 301 redirected to

```
  https://example.com/feeds/
```

or any URL with pattern `/74750882288885xxx/comments/default` returning 410 Gone.

Can someone help me with the `.htaccess` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to redirect the URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^feeds/\d+/comments/default /feeds/ [R=301,L]
```

The pattern `\d+` matches 1 or more digits. If the `/comments/default` part is not critical to make a match then it can be removed. If just matching a single digit is sufficient then change the regex to read: `^feeds/\d`, which would be more efficient.

Or to serve a 410 Gone instead, change the rule to read:

```
RewriteRule ^feeds/\d+/comments/default - [G]
```